# Using Google App Engine URL patterns to reach non-default service

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

According to [this doc][1] I should be able to reach a non-default service through URL patterns.

I am using a custom domain. (site.com) This is working to reach the default service.

I want to reach a second, non-default service called `my-service`.

According to the docs, it seems like this is the way to do it:

`my-service.site.com`

However, this isn't working. I understand I can use a `dispatch.yaml` file, but I would like to set it up just by the URL's if possible.

How do I set this up correctly?

Edit: The exact error (url replaced) is this:

```
This site can’t be reached
my-service.site.com’s server IP address could not be found.


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#default_routing
```

Answer (score -4):

The URL pattern you are using is correct. This problem is a DNS issue for "site.com".  It appears that while you have mapped "site.com" to App Engine, subdomains are not mapped to App Engine, thus the DNS lookup is failing.

You either need to ensure that you have a wildcard entry in place for site.com,  eg:

```
*.site.com.  3599    IN      CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com.
```

Or map the specific service subdomain(s) to Google.

```
my-service.site.com.  3599    IN      CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com.
```

This maps requests to subdomains of "site.com" to Google's servers.

Further details are in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#using_subdomains).

Comment: I did try setting that up, but I couldn't get it working with either option.  I will try it again tomorrow.