# Google App Engine URL pattern shows default service instead

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to setup our Google App Engine to have 4 services hosted under a custom domain, one for the naked domain and three subdomains, such that:

```
site.com -> Service: default
app.site.com -> Service: app
api.site.com -> Service: api
admin.site.com -> Service: admin
```

According to the documentation [How Requests are Routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-requests-are-routed#example_urls) and [Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains#using_subdomains), we should simply be able to rely on Google App Engines own URL pattern `SERVICE_ID.CUSTOM_DOMAIN` for the subdomains. We do not want to deal with a `dispatch.yaml` file, since it shouldn't be necessary and it'll complicate our CI/CD.

We've configured the custom domain A, AAAA and CNAME records in the Google Cloud console and mirrored the DNS config in our domain registrar.

The `site.com` naked domain correctly shows the default service, but the issue is that, so does all the other subdomains. They all just show the default service instead of the services they're supposed to. The services run just fine when using Google's `appspot.com` url, but for the custom domain, they all just point to the default service.

Someone asked a [similar question here a few of months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326076/using-google-app-engine-url-patterns-to-reach-non-default-service/62326828#62326828), but in our case we've already configured the CNAME entries for each of the specific services.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The answer you mention is not correct at all. Actually, the answer suggest to add `*.domain.com` and `service.domain.com` to DNS.

The issue with this answer is that is kind of obvious that those entries should be added to the DNS for the correct name resolution but this is only the half of the story.

After some testing I've found that the docs are not clear at all of the steps needed to make this approach working.

In your DNS it is not necessary to add `*.domain.com`, actually you can add the only needed subdomains in the DNS for your app like in your case:

```
app.site.com  3599    IN      CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com.
api.site.com  3599    IN      CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com.
admin.site.com  3599    IN      CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com.
site.com  3599    IN      A   [App Engine IPv4 IPs]
site.com  3599    IN      AAAA   [App Engine IPv6 IPs]
```

Now the trick to make this work is to add in App Engine the `*.domain.com` mapping. After doing this, the approach you mention should work.

Comment: We already created only the necessary subdomains to our DNS configuration. I've tried removing the individual subdomains from the GCP custom domains mapping, and replacing it with the wildcard `*.domain.com` mapping as suggested by your answer, but it did not fix the problem. The only effect it had, was that routing to the subdomain didn't work at all, instead of showing the default service.

Comment: Something I forgot to mention is that this take time to apply changes. As you I thought it was not working but after ~30 minutes the url was redirecting to the correct service.

Comment: Time doesn't seem to be the issue. Have tried different configurations every 1-2 hours the last couple of days with no change in result. It either doesn't resolve the route at all or it just routes to the default service regardless of which subdomain is requested.

Comment: I see. In this case I think that reaching GCP support could be an option, maybe they can see something else that we cannot.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably our next attempt. We can't justify spending any more time trying to make it work, so we've settled on using the `dispatch.yaml` file to define the routing for now - although it doesn't really play well with continuous deployment.